# Karaf stops unexpectedly

Tags: log4j2, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, karaf

After upgrading Karaf from 2.2.11 to 4.0.3 with log4j2 support and running load tests of our Karaf based application, Karaf unexpectedly starts shutdown process. 
We increased most of memory options but it did not help. 
No info in logs - just
"Stopping blueprint extender" and "Unregistering bundles...". Above these messages there was debug info from my bundles. In manifest files of our bundles old OSGI container is used (org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0"). This occurs  for single threaded scenario too, after 3 hours since karaf start.

Can one bundle that fails trigger whole framework to stop?

Any ideas why Karaf 4.0.3 is not stable and where we need to investigate?

Comment: Why don't you do a step by step migration of your bundles and then find out which bundle is causing the issue?

Comment: Use cases may be reproduced only with full set of bundles. But will try to apply you suggestion, thank you!