# Karaf 4.0.5 with log4j2: my bundle log output always in console but should be in file

Tags: log4j2, apache-karaf

I configured Karaf 4.0.5 in order to fix this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35288889/karaf-stops-unexpectedly?s=1|3.7849), but log output from my bundles is shown only in karaf console, not in the file. It works in Karaf 4.0.3.
Any ideas why the output from my bundles is present only in Karaf console? 
 The changes that I made to configure log4j2:

1. startup.properties (corresponding jars are in ${karaf.system} folder):

   mvn:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-api/1.8.5 = 8
   (this line is commented) mvn:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-service/1.8.5 = 8
   mvn:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-log4j2/1.8.5 = 8
   mvn:com.lmax/disruptor/3.3.2 = 8
2. org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg:

   org.ops4j.pax.logging.log4j2.config.file = ${karaf.etc}/log4j2.xml
   org.ops4j.pax.logging.log4j2.async = true
3. system.properties

   log4j.configurationFile=file:${karaf.etc}/log4j2.xml

   org.ops4j.pax.logging.DefaultServiceLog.level = DEBUG

   Log4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector
4. log4j2.xml:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Configuration status="ALL">    
   <Appenders>
       <RollingRandomAccessFile name="oapiserver" fileName="data/log/log4j2.log" filePattern="data/log/oapi-%d_%i.log.gz" immediateFlush="false">
           <ThresholdFilter level="DEBUG"/>
           <PatternLayout>
               <pattern>%level{length=1} %date{MMdd-HHmm:ss,SSS} %logger{1.} %message [%thread]%n</pattern>
           </PatternLayout>
           <Policies>
               <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
               <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB"/>
           </Policies>
           <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10000"/>
       </RollingRandomAccessFile>
   </Appenders>

   <Loggers>
       <Root level="DEBUG">
           <AppenderRef ref="oapiserver"/>
       </Root>
   </Loggers>
   ```

Comment: Were you able to fix it? I'm getting the same now with karaf 4.0.4 when trying to switch to log4j2. Everything is logged to console and minimum level is error, so looks like my config is just ignored (tried xml, yaml, my own config and samples from their site)

Comment: Check your output  - make sure that karaf picks up your config. I switched to karaf 4.0.3  - there are no problems.

Comment: So this is some bug with Karaf 4.0.4 and later? only 4.0.3 works?

Comment: There are no problems with karaf 4.0.3. I just swithched to karaf 4.0.3 and stopped investigation.

Answer (score 0):

For karaf-4.0.4 : 
see Release note for 4.0.5 - [**KARAF-4278**] - clean not working.
So Either delete data directory from karaf server after the configuration for log4j2.

For karaf-4.0.5:
Run karaf clean after configuration